# react-bootstrap is failing on import

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am trying to import react-bootstrap on my project like so:

```
import forwardRef from '@restart/context/forwardRef';
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
```

but getting compilation error:

```
Failed to compile.

../node_modules/@restart/context/forwardRef.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react' in '/Users/me/Projects/mypr/node_modules/@restart/context'
```

Comment: Did you "npm install react --save"?

Comment: yes I did that.